# Cypress test passes and does not wait for cy.request()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cypress

In one of my tests I need to make two request (second request depends on first response) and after that make some assertions. The problem is that test passes before getting response from server

Test File

```
it('My test', () => {
  makeReqs().then((res)=> {
    console.log(res);
    someAssertions
  })
})
```

Request functions

```
function first() {
  return Promise((resolve) => {
   something
   resolve('response')
  })
}

makeReqs() {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
    first().then((res) => {
      //here I use res in resObj
      cy.request({reqObj}).then(response => resolve(response.data))
    })
  }
}
```

Can someone help me? Still have some problems with asynchronous Cypress

Comment: It is tricky to mix Promises with Cypress. Try to make custom commands from those functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using promise/resolve within a Cypress test, add Mocha `done()` method to indicate when the test is done.

Cypress monitors promises on it's own queue, but you have not wrapped the promise in a command so it can't tell when the test is done.

```js
it('waits for done', (done) => {
  const promise = makeReqs()
  promise.then((data) => {
    //test the data
    done()
  })
})
```

Or add an async/await to the test, or wrap in a custom command to allow Cypress to monitor the promise.